# active button after check one or more checkbox in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some checkbox, and a button. Now, I want active button when one or more checkbox is checked. How can I do this in angularjs?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="check"> First</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check"> Second</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check"> Third</label>


<br>
<button type="button" disabled ng-model="$scope.btn">active/deactive</button>
```

Comment: save the values of the checkboxes with ng-model 
and use them in ng-disabled="!(checkboxValue1 || ch...)"

Comment: you want to activate button if two boxes are checked??

Comment: @SaEChowdary even if one of them is checked, one, two, three or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ng-model` to checkboxes

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check" ng-model="check1"> First</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check" ng-model="check2"> Second</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check" ng-model="check3"> Third</label>
```

And use [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) to disable\enable button

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="!check1 && !check2 && !check3" ng-model="$scope.btn">active/deactive</button>
```

Comment: suppose if i have n boxes??do i need to extend  upto !checkn??isnt there any simplest way?

Comment: hello @Razzaka i want to also using checkbox set button disable/enable but my check box is it store in datatable angulrjs. so i m assign ng-modal='check' liek this so i m check on chekbox at time all check box checked so can you idea how can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ng-disabled` directive on the button to add the disable attribute conditionally.

Check the below example where the input check boxes are bound to their respective properties on the controller's scope using the `ng-model` directive that serves two-way data binding in AngularJS.

Note: If you're having a complex condition to be checked in the view you can write a function and invoke it in the view using a corresponding directive in that situation.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.disableButton = disableButton;
    
    function disableButton() {
      if (vm.first || vm.second || vm.third) {
        return false;
      } else {
       return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check" ng-model="ctrl.first"> First</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check" ng-model="ctrl.second"> Second</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check" ng-model="ctrl.third"> Third</label>
    <br>
    <button type="button" ng-disabled="ctrl.disableButton()">active/deactive</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

1. save the values of the checkboxes with ng-model and use them in ng-disabled="!(checkboxValue1 || ch...)"
2. use ng-model for saving the values and ng-requried="!checkBox2Value && !checkbox3Value" with the checkboxes. Put a form around the checkboxes and use ng-disabled="formName.$invalid"